# Customize Gii Code Generator For Internal Use

Tags: yii, generator, gii

I am new to yii.I want to use Gii Code Generator in my application for generate model and CRUD dynamically.Like i am giving rights to choose field for their form.They enter details for fields and click button for generate form at that time in back hand i want to generate table for that all field, model and crude for that.I can generate table in back hand but when i want to generate model and crude i have show interface of gii. I can't hide it from User so please help me out if any one knew how to generate all in back hand.please.

Comment: Word of advice. Don't... Generating your code with Gii adds a lot of mess. If you still want to continue with it, try creating your own Gii templates

Comment: @SnIpY: i m using my own templets but i want to use its mechanism for generating code in backhand.